# Why does SiteMap.CurrentNode return null after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-6

I recently upgraded a website to ASP.NET 4.0 and after moving the code to a staging server, every time i browse to a page directory like mysite.com/bacon/ the SiteMap.CurrentNode is null.  However, if i browse mysite.com/bacon/default.aspx it works fine.  The server and site are configured for 4.0 and the document defaults are set default.aspx is the first page to default to.

I should also mention this behavior is not happening on my local dev machine, it recognizes that mysite.com/bacon/ is really mysite.com/bacon/default.aspx and the SiteMap.CurrentNode is set accordingly.

Comment: did you get any answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the SiteMap provider was using HttpContext.Request.rawUrl.
For some reason in the change from .Net 2.0 to 4.0 rawurl no longer will return your default document, so used HttpContext.Request.Path instead.

Comment: ***HttpContext.Current.Request.Path***

Answer (score 0):

check the url of your Web.sitemap nodes (if you use such file!) and don't forget to add "/" at the end of urls. for example, this will produce error:

```
<siteMapNode title="bacon" url="mysite.com/bacon" description="" >
```

but this is correct:

```
<siteMapNode title="bacon" url="mysite.com/bacon/" description="" >
```